# HBase scan based on time range. Does it scan all regions and all rows for the table or does it uses timestamp indexing to filter out rows?

Tags: hbase

**Use Case**

I want to perform hourly roll up on my 1 year data. For that, I will be running scans for hourly data like below

`scan 't1', {COLUMNS => 'c1', TIMERANGE => [1692748800000, 1692752400000]}`

Want to understand

1. HBase will run scan on the entire 1 year data
2. HBase will use indexing on the timestamp field to filter out rows